# Convert Object column to number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working with a python dataframe and there is a names column with different names in the form of strings.

I try to convert these names into individual numbers so for example:

```
"Paul" 1
"John" 2
"Nina" 3
...
```

I already tried

```
dataset['name'] = dataset['name'].astype(np.int64)
```

and this:

```
dataset = dataset.astype({'collection_author':'int'})
```

Which both lead to the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

and also this:

```
dataset['name'] = pd.to_numeric(dataset['name'])
```

which leads to:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "John" at position 0
```

If I add the `errors='coerce'` the code runs through however most of the values are replaced with NaN.

Comment: are you trying to make the values Categorical? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: `dataset['name'] = dataset.groupby('name').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: @richardec unfortenantely all the names have been converted to one so there is no uniqueness anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies) or [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to convert strings to ints.